# Fix Errors using Custom Formula in google Sheet with Script (getRange)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a google Sheet where i want to get the background colors of the specify range (Cells) using custom formula with script.

within the Cell A1, i put the custom function: =gh(B1:D1)

In script:
function gh(Cells) {
var Hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('PROGRAMA SST');
const Colores = Hoja.getRange(Cells).getBackgrounds();
return Colores;
};

however, i get error "Exception Range not found".
Note: I know if i put =gh("B1:D1") the script works but i want to avoid putting the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a range reference to a text string in `A1` notation with a named function, and use it in your custom function formulas like this:

`=gh( GETRANGEA1(B1:D1) )`

To create the named function, choose **Data > Named functions** and use these parameters:

Function name: `GETRANGEA1`

Function description: `Converts a range reference to a text string in A1 notation.`

Argument placeholders: `range`

Formula definition:

```
=substitute( 
  cell("address", range) 
  & ":" & 
  reduce( 
    _, range, 
    lambda( 
      result, lastCell, 
      cell("address", lastCell) 
    ) 
  ), 
  "$", ""  
)
```

Comment: thanks doubleunary